# Is there a way to automatically clone the Git repositories from Azure DevOps to local with schedule?

Tags: git, azure-devops

I would like to try to do automatically clone the Git repositories from Azure DevOps to local drive with schedule like every 15 minutes.
I'm trying to do like that because I would like to reduce the manual cloning process for everyday to get latest from Azure DevOps into local drive.

Since we have a lot of source codes maintained in Azure Devops, we don't want to give access to junior developers to access that Azure DevOps directly.
So,we would like to give them the local drive which has the latest source codes and these source codes need to be latest.
That's why I'm trying to do like that.

I'm also thinking like by running this cloning process in batch file and run with window task scheduler.
But I would like to know the advice from you guys.
If you know the similar way or better way of doing it, please advice me.

Comment: If you have lots of repos you don't want junior developers to have access to, why not just restrict that with security.  Pulling local to give to developers and having them work from that defeats the purpose of a source control system..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to define a yaml pipeline to clone the Git repository from Azure DevOps to local with schedule.

For example:

```
trigger:
- master

schedules:
- cron: "*/15 * * * *"
  displayName: clone repo to local
  branches:
    include:
    - master
  always: true

pool: Default      

steps:
- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: 'git clone https://<PAT>@dev.azure.com/{org}/{pro}/_git/{repo} D:\test2'
```

Note: To clone a repo to local , you need to set private agent pool .

`git clone` clones the repository from the URL in a folder under the current one. You can specify a folder name after the URL to create the repo in a specific location. You can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/clone?view=azure-devops&tabs=command-line#clone-a-repo).

About Scheduled triggers syntax, please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/scheduled-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#supported-cron-syntax).

Comment: Is it a way to use it for multiple repositories but one at the time?